# Add non-existing factors to ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, factors

I have a theoretical range of factors from M1 to M11. In the data M1 to M3 and M5 doesn't exist. How can I ggplot2 barplot with all Ms, not only the existing, so that M1 to M3 and M5 are also shown in the x-axis?

Comment: add  `+ scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)`

Comment: Not possible because M1 to M3 and M5 DONT exist in the data. Levels: M10 M11 M4 M6 M7 M8 M9

Comment: See suggested answer below on reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not reproducible, so I'll illustrate on a stand alone code

If you"ll run

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar()
```

You'll get

[image]

If you wish to add unused levels to `factor(cyl)` you can use `scale_x_discrete` using `limits` and `drop = F`.

For Example

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar() + 
scale_x_discrete(limits = c(1, 2, levels(factor(mtcars$cyl)), 10), drop=FALSE)
```

Will produce

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your factor is capable of having all those levels at some point, it makes more sense to set the levels of the factor than to add it to the limits when you `ggplot` it. So:

Make `cyl` a factor starting with M (So M4, M6 and M8 only)

```
mtcars$cyl=factor(paste("M",mtcars$cyl,sep=""))
```

Augment the levels:

```
mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl, levels=paste("M",1:10,sep=""))
```

Now its just a `drop=FALSE` in your `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) + geom_bar() + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

Why do I think this is better? Well, because you have tied an aspect of your data (the possible levels) with the data itself, rather than a plotting function. Suppose you have a bunch of plotting functions, now you have to code that level fix in each of them. Put the possible levels in the factor and that information is carried around with the data. All you need to do is decide on `drop=FALSE` or `drop=TRUE` at plot time.